# inf not convertible to a float

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point, overflowexception

For some reason after a while my code raises,
`OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer`.
I can't see any reason why it would do this, there is little use of floats and no use of the inf,

```
def bugsInCode(begin):
    bugs = begin
    while bugs != 0:
        print "%s bugs in the code, %s bugs\ntake one down patch it around, %s bugs in the code!" % (bugs, bugs, int(bugs * 1.5))
        bugs = int(bugs * 1.5)
```

However replacing `1.5` with a `1` or a `2` works. Why?

Comment: I just noticed the code is a bit self referential!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bugs * 1.5` is a floating-point operation because of the floating-point operand (`1.5`), which you convert back to an integer. Note `bugs * 2` and `bugs * 1` are integer operations, because of the integer operands.

It is always increasing, at an exponential rate (`bugs = int(bugs * 1.5)`).

Eventually `bugs` will be an integer large enough such that `bugs * 1.5` will exceed the maximum allowable value of a floating-point number, and thus will be "infinity". Then you try to convert that back to an integer, hence the error message, which is accurate.

`bugs * 2` (integer operation as mentioned) works because there is no concept of "infinity" or an overflow error for integers. `bugs * 1`, of course, just runs forever. `bugs * 2.0`, however, would fail.

Comment: "the integers just wrap around" is a bit misleading: there's no integer wraparound (in the sense of automatic reduction modulo some power of 2) in plain Python.  (NumPy is a different matter, of course.)

Comment: So if I wanted it to grow at a rate of 1.5 what should I do?

Comment: @tox123 I'd say don't convert it to an int. But I can't give better advice than that. I don't actually know python. I'm sure there's a way to print a float with 0 decimal places; probably `"%.0f bugs in the code ..."`.